# Did Kick-Heart reveal a breakdown of its expenses?

Tags: anime-production, kick-heart

*Kick-Heart* is notable as the first anime to be crowdfunded via [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/production-ig/masaaki-yuasas-kick-heart).

The base goal of the Kickstarter was to reach $150,000, with additional stretch goals for more money.

On their campaign page, they tell potential backers how they intended to use the funds raised:

> - Increase the quality of animation
> - Increase the overall duration of the animation
> - Help offset the current production costs
> - Manufacturing costs for backers rewards (Blu-ray, printed materials, etc.)
> - Digital distribution costs for backers downloading the film
> - Festival submission fees

Do they mention the breakdown of expenses anywhere? I couldn't find it on their Kickstarter page. Generally speaking, it's not uncommon for crowdfunded projects to show where your money goes. Was it perhaps revealed in a backer-only update (which I wouldn't have access to)?

I just thought it was odd that the amount was so high compared to latter Kickstarters like Santa Company for $50,000, which was also a longer animation.

Comment: doesn't answer your question, but relevant i think - have you looked at Under the Dog's [kickstart](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1300298569/under-the-dog/description)? Its about 4x the cost, there's also a cost break down on the description page.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a breakdown beyond what you quote, though http://www.cartoonbrew.com/ideas-commentary/72508-72508.html has a bit of commentary on it.